# Keep values in search form after submit

Tags: php, forms

How can the field values from a search form be kept (safely) after form submission in PHP?

Is this method safe?

```
<input type="checkbox" ... ="<?php if(isset($_POST['ThisRadioIsChecked'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>" ... />
```

Comment: That is relatively safe, but take note: If you're applying said input to textboxes/textareas (where user input is supplied), you'll need to escape it and all as it can be easily exploited.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like :

```
<form action="this_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

You can set the search input value with the `$_POST` array (or `$_GET` if you used GET method).

```
<?php

// if data 'search' posted in POST method, make it safe in HTML then store it in $search. If 'search' data was not posted, fill it with an empty string ('')
$search = (isset($_POST['search'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['search']) : '';

?>

<form action="this_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." value="<?= $search ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

I have to explain you that short tags will maybe not be parsed by PHP if your php.ini file contains : `short_open_tag = Off`

Then you will have to use the standard method to do it : `<?php echo $search; ?>` rather than short one : `<?= $search ?>`

By the way, this line is maybe a bit confusing for not advanced users :

```
$search = (isset($_POST['search'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['search']) : '';
```

You can replace it by :

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $search = htmlentities($_POST['search']);
}
else
{
    $search = '';
}
```

Or even :

```
$search = '';

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $search = htmlentities($_POST['search']);
}
```

By the way, if you want to be able to not keep the value :

```
<?php

// if data 'search' posted in POST method, make it safe in HTML then store it in $search. If 'search' data was not posted, fill it with an empty string ('')
$search = (isset($_POST['search'])) ? htmlentities($_POST['search']) : '';
// if reset asked, then empty $search
$search = (isset($_POST['reset'])) ? '' : $search;

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." value="<?= $search ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Go"><?php if($search != '') echo '<input type="submit" name="reset" value="Reset">'; ?>
</form>
```

You could also use a checkbox or something ... :)

Comment: Use short tags instead of echo. value="<?= $search ?>"

Comment: there was a good review but it was automaticly rejected, idk why, maybe I took too long to look at it ... Anyway, gona edit with short method :)

Comment: Thanks @Bob0t. How can I use always the placeholder when there is no value present?  I can do it but I need the placeholder to when it is empty. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want :/ The placeholder is shown if the value is empty so if `$search = ''` the placeholder will be shown.

Comment: Oh damn, just understood what you mean, yes, if the value is empty, the placeholder will be shown, just try it, you will see ;)